# how to get view data value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have

```
 <%var test = ViewData["test"];%>

 <ul class= "list" id = "<%test;%>">
```

but having error message:

> Only assignment, call, increment,
>   decrement, and new object expressions
>   can be used as a statement

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <ul class= "list" id = "<%=ViewData["test"]%>">
```

Answer (score 4):

Your output block needs to use `<%= %>` or `<%: %>` if you want it encoded, like this:

```
<ul class="list" id="<%=test%>">
```

Though, unless you need the variable all over the place, just use `<%= %>` on the original `ViewData["test"]`, it's a bit cleaner, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
<ul class= "list" id = "<%=test%>">
```

...you were missing the '=' symbol before 'test' & added an extra ';' after it.